# Is there a way to show build status/code coverage per branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are setting the CI on our GitLab and we are able to show build status and code coverage on master using the following:

`README.md` in root directory of `myproject`:

```
[![build status](http://mygitlab/mygroup/myproject/badges/master/build.svg)](http://mygitlab/mygroup/myproject/commits/master) 
[![coverage report](http://mygitlab/mygroup/myproject/badges/master/coverage.svg)](http://mygitlab/mygroup/myproject/commits/master)
```

Something we would like is show build status/code coverage of current branch when viewing the `README.md` in the branch. Right now, the links have `master` hardcoded so the branches show the status of the master.

Is there a way to use relative URL (or something else) so the build status / code coverage automatically adapt to the branch you're viewing? Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html), it looks like it's impossible, because you have to specify the branch.

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way. This is in fact a weakness in exposing this information via these readme markdown-embedding URLs.   For long lived branches, I have been creating WIKIs to contain the coverage information.    For local viewing of all branches, I think a feature request could be made to have Gitlab's ruby front end show a dashboard-like view of all branches, with their CI status, code coverage, and other stuff.  For short lived branches, this kind of information is noise, and not signal, at least, where I work.

Comment: @WarrenP I guess you're right. Our branches have a short life span (± 2 weeks), so it might not add much value to have that information.

Comment: What I would really like to see is what the Code coverage was Before and After a merge request, while reviewing merge requests. Oh look, your code coverage went up with this MR! yay! Oh look it went down in this MR! sadness!

Comment: For long-lived branches, maybe put all of this information in a table in the README.md for the default branch?  Or even have a separate project that acts as a dashboard that has a readme?

Comment: @WarrenP Could you (in the CI script) append to a CSV file living in the project's Wiki? Then some code could graph that data and make it look pretty somewhere else.

Comment: @ahogen we do something similar. CI triggers a script for every merge in `master` and the coverage data is inserted in a database. We can plot the data to see the evolution in time.

Comment: You can add to README.md and update via your CI pipeline as I have shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77610730/9022092

Answer (score 1):

Starting in GitLab 9.3 (available only in Starter/Bronze and higher), code quality will be evaluated as part of the CI/CD pipeline and the results will display in the merge request.

You can see an example of how this looks in a merge request in the documentation at [GitLab Code Quality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html).

This works 'automatically' via Auto DevOps or you can configure Code Quality manually by using the [Code Quality examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/code_quality.html)

This doesn't address showing code quality and pipeline status for a given branch in the README. As mentioned, it does show the pipeline status and code quality in the MR itself. However, when viewing a particular branch, the commit at the top of the page does show the overall pipeline status. Click on that status to go to the pipeline for more detailed job information, including the Code Quality job itself.

[image: branch commit pipeline status]

It's not quite as handy as what you're looking for, but it is a workaround. Usually, concerns about quality and build status are most important on the proposed merge request itself, where fixes can be made prior to merging them into the master/target branch.

Answer (score 1):

> What I would really like to see is what the Code coverage was Before and After a merge request, while reviewing merge requests

Actually, this is easier with [GitLab 13.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/22/gitlab-13-4-released/#show-job-data-for-code-coverage-value-in-mr) (September 2020)

> ### Show job data for Code Coverage value in MR
>
> As a developer, you should be able to easily see code coverage after a pipeline finishes running, even in complex scenarios that make this more difficult, like when your pipeline has multiple jobs that are parsed to calculate the coverage value.
>
> Until now, the Merge Request widget only showed the average of those values, which meant you had to navigate to the jobs page and then back to the Merge Request itself to get more granular details for the coverage value.
>
> To save you time and eliminate those extra steps, you’re now presented with the average coverage value, how it has changed from the target and source branch, and a tooltip that shows the coverage for each job used to calculate the average.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_4/coverage-tooltip.png -- Show job data for Code Coverage value in MR]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-parsing) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15399).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to show build status/code coverage per branch

One new feature which does relate to this is with [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#pipeline-status-in-branch-and-tag-lists) (November 2020):

> ### Pipeline status in branch and tag lists
>
> If you use CI/CD pipelines with tags or branches and want to know the latest pipeline status, you previously had to navigate away from the branch list or tag list to get to the pipeline page. Now, pipeline status icons are displayed for each branch or tag in their respective list views so you can quickly get to this information for many tags or branches in less clicks.
>
> Thanks to [Lee Tickett](https://gitlab.com/leetickett) for this contribution!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_6/pipeline_status_tag_list.png -- Pipeline status in branch and tag lists]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#view-pipelines) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14124).