# How to show gitlab badges per branch in readme.md

Tags: gitlab, badge

I am trying to show the build status of my branch on that branch's readme.md.
`https://mygitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/coverage.svg`  I tried [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html) but branch place holder isn't getting evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a README.md with the following for each branch

```
[![Coverage](https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/coverage.svg)](https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/)
```

**for example:**

Master Branch README.md

[image: Coverage]

Other Branch README.md

[image: Coverage]

Comment: Is it possible to show badges without hardcoding link in readme?

Comment: Just dont add the link inside the ()

Comment: There are 2 sets of parentheses here, I believe the asker is looking for a way to have the readme file show the badge for the *current branch*, not a specific branch that is specified in the file.

Comment: Did you find the solution?
Is there a way to write a placeholder in the badge URL, as the current branch?

Answer (score 0):

Per [GitLab issue: 27093](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27093) this is not yet possible with a placeholder.

However it is possible to use GitLab CI to auto update the badges (similar to what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716044/how-do-i-push-to-a-repo-from-within-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline)).

In your .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
update_readme:
  script:
    - sed -ie "s/badges\/.*\/coverage/badges\/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH\/coverage/g" README.md
    - git config user.email $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
    - git config user.name $GITLAB_USER_NAME
    # add must be used on first run per runner, on subsequent runs error is caught
    - git remote add gitlab_origin https://$GITLAB_ACCESS_USER:$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git || true
    - git remote set-url gitlab_origin https://$GITLAB_ACCESS_USER:$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
    - git add README.md
    #  don't fail if no changes
    - git commit -m "push back from pipeline - README.md" || true
    # prevent triggering pipeline again
    - git push gitlab_origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH -o ci.skip || true
```

This assumes your README.md contains:

```markdown
[![Coverage](https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/coverage.svg)](https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/)
```

$GITLAB_ACCESS_USER and $GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN are in [CI Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/).

The Token can be a [Project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) or [Group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) access token. The `user` can be whatever you like.

You must also make sure your Project -> Settings -> Repository -> Push Rules have `Reject unverified users` turned off as the pushing user will not match the committing user.