# How do I push to a repo from within a gitlab CI pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my CI pipeline I am generating an artifact `public/graph.png` that visualises some aspect of my code. In a later step I want to commit that to the repo from within the CI pipeline. Here's the pertinent part of `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
commit-graph:
  stage: pages
  script:
    - git config user.email "cipipeline@example.com"
    - git config user.name "CI Pipeline"
    - cd /group/project
    - mv public/graph.png .
    - git add graph.png
    - git commit -m "committing graph.png [ci skip]"
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - git push origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

When the pipeline runs within gitlab it fails with:

> $ git config user.email "cipipeline@dhgitlab.dunnhumby.co.uk"
>   $ git config user.name "CI Pipeline"
>   $ cd /group/project
>   $ mv public/graph.png .
>   $ git add graph.png
>   $ git commit -m "committing graph.png [ci skip]"
>   [detached HEAD 22a50d1] committing graph.png [ci skip]
>    1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>    create mode 100644 graph.png
>   $ echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
>   jamiet/my-branch
>   $ git push origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@example.com/group/project/project.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Not sure what I'm doing wrong and don't know enough about SSL to understand that error. Can anyone advise?

We are hosting gitlab ourselves by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Issuing `git config --global http.sslverify "false"` prior to the push solved that particular problem (it exposed another problem but that's for another thread :) )

Comment: Good question, but -1 to this answer because it encourages avoiding the problem rather than fixing it. There are good ways to get a free SSL certificate these days, there should be no excuse not to fix the SSL problem rather than disabling it entirely.

Answer (score 89):

Nowadays there is a much cleaner way to solve this without using SSH but using a [project scoped access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html), also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication).

In the GitLab project create an [project scoped access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) so it is linked to the project, not to an individual. Next store this token as an GitLab CI/CD variable. You can now connect using the following:

```
push-back-to-remote:
  script:
    - git config user.email "my-email@email.com"
    - git config user.name "ci-bot"
    - git remote add gitlab_origin https://oauth2:$ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/path-to-project.git
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "push back from pipeline"
    - git push gitlab_origin HEAD:main -o ci.skip # prevent triggering pipeline again
```

Comment: Sounds like the best option, though Project Access Tokens are available only for Premium or higher tiers.

Comment: Best solution! Project Access Tokens are available on self hosted instances.
But caution: They will need an expiry date from GitLab 16 on!

Comment: For the record, SSH deploy key isn't linked to any individual either.

Comment: Note: Project Access Tokens are available for all tiers on self-managed instances.

Comment: There is a [bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/388743) with access token creation in gitlab to be aware of

Comment: If your git pushes get rejected because of the enabled setting "Repository Settings > Push Rules > Reject unverified users", please note that every Project Access Token implicitly creates a "bot user" that also comes with an email address that represents a verified user. So you can solve the issue by setting the git's "user.email" config to the bot's email address - as per the [pattern description in the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#bot-users-for-projects).

Comment: Great answer!! Specially logged in to upvote this 

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get this solution to work when we've turned on commit sigining on our repos? Trying to sign it with `git commit -S -m "push back from pipeline"` results in `error: gpg failed to sign the data`.

Answer (score 29):

### TL;DR;

If you just want to make a `release` or version bump commits when stuff is merged to `main`, there are probably existing CLI tools that you can use in a much more simpler and well documented way.
*(See **Use the gitlab `api`** for an example)*

### How to do it

###### The necessary steps:

```yaml
commitingJob:
  stage: some_stage
  script:
    # in order to commit we have to have a user set
    # this would also make it easy to distinct the CI-made commits
    - git config user.name "CI Pipeline"
    - git config user.email "cipipeline@example.com"
    # stage some changes
    - git add src/*
    # We can use `-o ci.skip`, but AFAIK it doesn't work for Merge Request pipelines, while having it inside the commit message works there as well
    - git commit -m "A commit message [skip ci]"
    # we're on a detached head but we can push the commits we made to the remote branch like so:
    - git push HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

One thing missing here is authenticating with the remote. It can be setup in a number of ways (ssh, token, api). Other answers discuss a few different options. My preference would be to use an ACCESS_TOKEN, see how and why bellow

### Summary and critique on the available authentication options

#### Adding or copying an `ssh` key inside the CI steps

Compared to just using an access token, going for the `ssh` way seems like too much work, for the same result

- generate an ssh key
- save the public key as Project [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#deploy-tokens)
- save the private key as a Project CI variable
- dedicate a few CI steps on

  - adding the private keys
  - adding known hosts
  - add/update the `ssh` remote

Overall it seems like something you'd do for a `user` and not for a pipeline

You have to add the private key as a Project Level CI variable - due to pattern restrictions the variable can't be masked. It can be added as a file, but then you'd have to `chmod` for proper permissions...

The positive thing I see here is the `ssh` key is restricted only to the projects you add it to as deploy token

---

#### The easiest option seems to be to use an ACCESS_TOKEN

Using a token to push commits is as easy as updating the `push` remote like this:

```bash
git remote set-url --push origin "https://$TOKEN_NAME:$ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/<project>.git"
```

TOKEN_NAME - the name you set for the token in gitlab (preferably pick a name without space characters)
ACCESS_TOKEN - this can be a [personal access token (Free Tier)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) or a [project access token (Premium Tier)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html)

It would have to be stored as Project Level CI variable, and it can be masked.
I would just save a variable like `CI_COMMITTER_USER_AND_TOKEN` containing both `<token_name>:<access_token>` content

###### ⚠ Warning about Personal Access Tokens

**This is too broad permission to give to a CI Runner** even if the runner should commit to multiple repositories, I'll prefer separate access tokens per project with only the minimum permissions needed

Keep in mind that if someone takes hold of your personal access token, they can do stuff (like committing in this case) on your behalf. Giving the `write_repository` permission means you can use the token to write to any repository you're account has access too.

###### CI_JOB_TOKEN

If you're wondering whether you can use the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to push commits - you can't. You can only `pull` with that thing
*(You can also use it to publish packages and images, but not push commits)*

###### Why `git remote set-url --push origin`

We can add a separate remote for CI made commits, but keep in mind it might get cached, so if we just do

```bash
script: 
  - git remote add ci "https://$TOKEN_NAME:$ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/<project>.git"
```

the next time the pipeline runs we'll get an error from `git remote add`, because the remote we're trying to add is already added

`set-url` on the existing `origin` makes sure you use the latest url

To achieve the same with `git remote add` we'd have to first try to remove the `ci` remote and then add it back

```bash
script: 
  - git remote remove ci || true
  - git remote add ci "https://$TOKEN_NAME:$ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/<project>.git"
```

---

#### Use the gitlab `api` to push changes

This works pretty much the same way as the `ACCESS_TOKEN` way, but instead of the `write_repository` the token has the `api` permission

If the reason to commit and push as part of CI is releasing a new version on merge to `main` then using CLI tools and a guide like this might be a better option than setting up the committing and pushing yourself: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/semantic-release.html

The above guide setups a version bump, package updates, and release notes.
Note how this step instructs us to create an Access Token with `api` permission in order for the underlying CLIs to commit the changes: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/semantic-release.html#set-up-cicd-variables

Answer (score 22):

Some finger push-ups still required, but here's a less brittle way of pushing to the repository from its own CI, that I use in my daily work. It pushes to master directly from a detached head:

[image]

1. Generate an RSA key and add it as a [Project Deploy Key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/#project-deploy-keys) with write access (the public part).
2. Put the private part into your CI/CD variables from inside of your project settings as `SSH_PUSH_KEY`. Make sure to set it as protected.
3. Add a `CI_KNOWN_HOSTS` variable, with the SSH fingerprint of your GitLab instance (remember that thing `ssh` asks you about the first time you try to connect to a host? That.).

Use `ssh-keyscan <gitlab-host>` to get it. It will look similar to this:

```
my.gitlab.instance.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArlUMUmNj59PpoLyy4EsKbwhPUfXxuAzFN7dMKDXVvKMmN8344HqQV1tRx6fcmH+0BXK1JAP4f10V0VnYti3e1c5f9dhpl8pIqKLMJgdGDq3MLqjihL3bp5xm8nDsPTm5FoEPPYK1I3M2wr18pBB19evz64NHrK5R/HO5LyTrybVasFumt8cZoH6crnCFgfQWV1mHAG3j41Q0z4yxu6g8zBWESZcVVn90HxQH7+LDHx11122233344491MQGl5fZcKqVWsWQVEssaK87iBsWUxvsuoeVUrj4YRcmbi6F4+ZZZZZZZwwww3ZboWsSWxTk5ESR6WWHccBm8GQflXyY3ZQ==
```

4. Set up your job inside `.gitlab-ci.yml` as follows. Set [`stage`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stage) and [`resource_group`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#resource_group) options appropriately - without the latter you might run into race conditions. Also, make sure to set [`only`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) properly, as otherwise your CI might trigger itself:

```
"This CI job pushes to its own repo":
    stage: my_push_stage
    resource_group: this_option_comes_handy_when_pushing
    only:
        - triggers
    before_script:
        - mkdir ~/.ssh/
        - echo "${CI_KNOWN_HOSTS}" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - echo "${SSH_PUSH_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - git config user.email "ci@example.com"
        - git config user.name "CI"
        - git remote remove ssh_origin || true  # Local repo state may be cached
        - git remote add ssh_origin "git@$CI_SERVER_HOST:$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git"
    script:
        - touch "xyz"  # Make an edit
        - git add "xyz"
        - git commit -m "My CI commit"
        - git push ssh_origin HEAD:master  # ❗ this pushes to master, 
                                           # use $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME if you want to push to current branch
        - git tag MyCiTag  # If you need to add a tag you can do that too
        - git push --tags ssh_origin
```

Comment: you can use 

ssh-keyscan $CI_SERVER_HOST > ~/.ssh/known_hosts

rather than a variable

Comment: @TomChiverton While this works, it's basically the same as setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"`.

Comment: Deploy keys are not able to write to repositories. Thus this solution does no longer work.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu you are confusing deploy _keys_ with deploy _tokens_. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/ _"A read-write deploy key can read from, and write to, the repository."_

Answer (score 11):

I found this [GitLab forum](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18106#note_12209180) link helpful
As suggested by the user you need to generate SSH key, associate it with new GitLab user dedicated for this job and add key to the runner. Small drawback is you need to use swap origin in gitlab for original ssh source (instead of sandboxed one used inside the job) which leads to committer being changed to mentioned new account instead of person who triggered pipeline.
Source from link:

```
# for your information
whoami
printenv

# we need to extract the ssh/git URL as the runner uses a tokenized URL
export CI_PUSH_REPO=`echo $CI_REPOSITORY_URL | perl -pe 's#.*@(.+?(\:\d+)?)/#git@\1:#'`

# runner runs on a detached HEAD, create a temporary local branch for editing
git checkout -b ci_processing
git config --global user.name "My Runner"
git config --global user.email "runner@gitlab.example.org"
git remote set-url --push origin "${CI_PUSH_REPO}"

# make your changes
touch test.txt

# push changes
# always return true so that the build does not fail if there are no changes
git push origin ci_processing:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} || true
```

Just with current version of GitLab you need to change source variable name as follows:

```
export CI_PUSH_REPO=`echo $CI_REPOSITORY_URL | perl -pe 's#.*@(.+?(\:\d+)?)/#git@\1:#'`
```

Comment: I used `git checkout -b "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"` to create a branch with the same name as the remote branch 

Answer (score 11):

You can add the `CI_SERVER_CLS_CA_FILE` to `sslCAInfo` git config.

```yaml
checkout alchemy:
    stage: prepare
    script:
        - git config --global "http.${CI_SERVER_URL}.sslCAInfo" "$CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE"
        - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/sparklemuffin/alchemy.git
```

@Sjoerd's approach, in the comments, to export `GIT_SSL_CAINFO` instead, is a bit shorter.

```sh
export GIT_SSL_CAINFO=$CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
```

Gitlab creates `CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE` and configures git to use it for initially cloning the repository. For some reason this configuration is no longer available later on.

Comment: I used a similar solution: I put `export GIT_SSL_CAINFO="$CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE"` at the top of my script. It [doesn't work if you put it under `variables`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/292220).

Comment: ...and the second line of the script can be simplified to `git clone ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}`...

Comment: very elegant, unfortunately doesn't work for pushing to protected branches

Answer (score 3):

Instead of declaring CI_KNOWN_HOST, you can try get it realtime:

```
- 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
- ssh-keyscan -t rsa $CI_SERVER_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

I can commit from Gitlab-CI with a selected user with a minor change based on tsr's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57800614/5269825 :

```
# set remote URL to https://oauth2:<AccessToken>@server.com/project.git
CI_PUSH_REPO=`echo "$CI_REPOSITORY_URL $ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM" | sed 's/^.*\(@.*\)\s\(.*\)/https:\/\/oauth2:\2\1/g'`
git config http.sslverify false
git remote set-url --push origin "${CI_PUSH_REPO}"
git config user.name "Token Owner"
git config user.email "tokenowner@email.com"

# runner runs on a detached HEAD, create a temporary local branch for editing
git checkout -b ci_processing
# make your changes

# push changes
# always return true so that the build does not fail if there are no changes
git push origin ci_processing:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} || true
```

The `ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM` must be configured at the project's CI/CD Variables configuration.

The idea of using Oauth2 and Access Token was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074198/5269825 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52154378/5269825.

Also, pushing changes can trigger a new pipeline!

Answer (score 0):

In my case [deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/) option was optimal (compared to personal tokens or CI token - only supports basic auth) with Gitlab Shell Runner. In case someone is struggling  with pushing to from Gitlab CI, this can be done sharing the public key of the runner with the Gitlab server

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example as of today
environment: k8s
gitlab: 13.x
gitlab runner: 13.x
goal of this job named convert:- Converts the excel files to json files and commits and updates the branch of the repo.

```
convert:
  variables:
    REPO: "gitlab.com/group/myproject.git" # example
    BRANCH: "BRANCHNAME" # example
    # recommended to store the following as project variables to hide secrets away from the gitlab ci file.
    GITLAB_USER_ID: "gitlab_user" # example
    CI_USERNAME: "gitlab_user" # example
    CI_PUSH_TOKEN: "<api token from gitlab" # example
    GITLAB_USER_EMAIL: "gitlab_user@company.com" # example
  stage: convert
  image:
    name: python:3.7-buster
    entrypoint: ["/bin/ash"]
  before_script:
    - pip3 install openpyxl
    - ls -altr
  script:
    - echo 'converting excel to json'
    - python excel2json.py
    - git remote set-url origin https://${CI_USERNAME}:${CI_PUSH_TOKEN}@$REPO
    - git config --global user.email '${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}'
    - git config --global user.name '${GITLAB_USER_ID}'
    - git add -A && git commit -m 'added/updated json files'
    - git push origin HEAD:$BRANCH
```

Note: CI_USERNAME == GITLAB_USER_ID. Both are same in my case.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked immediately for me but I merged them all together to come up with this:

```
- git config user.email "example@example.com"
- git config user.name "example"
- git remote remove dev || true
- git remote add dev https://example:$PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/demo/versioning-test.git
- git remote set-url --push origin "https://example:$PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/demo/versioning-test.git"
- git pull origin dev
- git checkout dev 
- git reset --hard origin/dev
- git rm build_number.json || true
#grabs the build number from tags and pipes it into text file json formatted
- echo "`echo {'"build_number"':` `git describe --tags` `echo }`" | sed -e 's/\s\+/"/g' >> build_number.json
- git add build_number.json
- git commit -m "push back from pipeline [skip ci]"
- git push origin dev
```

My use case was that we wanted to bump to a version file and push that back into the repo.

Answer (score -2):

Another way:

1. Create dedicated Gitlab account
2. Add CI/CD variable GIT_CICDUSER_PASSWORD containing it's password to the project inside the main account running the pipeline

Then a job can look like:

```
task_requiring_a_push:
  stage: some-stage
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - git config --global user.email "user@mail.com"
    - git config --global user.name "CI/CD User"
    - git clone https://<dedicated_gitlab_user_username>:$GIT_CICDUSER_PASSWORD@gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH .
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - # do something
    - git add *
    - git commit -m "message"
    - git push --push-option=ci.skip origin $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
only:
    - release-*
```