# Deleting a branch using gitlab-ci.yml script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to delete a branch using  gitlab-ci.yml.
But it shows "you are not allowed to upload the script".
I am using the script as in the image. Is there anything else that we need to do to delete the script using pipeline?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to push any changes to your repo while you are using the pipeline, you cannot use the "git push origin --delete  command directly. You have to use a similar way of local branch delete (git branch -d  ) and push your code.

Here is an example on how you can push the changes to GitLab repo from your pipeline - [How do I push to a repo from within a gitlab CI pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716044/how-do-i-push-to-a-repo-from-within-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes Implemented in that way itself... We integrated it to a ec2 instance and did that