# .gitlab-ci.yaml not adding License file

Tags: git, macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to make sure my Repo has a proper license file.  I am trying to do this via the pipeline.  My runner is running on a Mac.  The runner is registered as shell and running. According to the pipeline it passes, but the LICENSE file is not created.  When I run it again, it still passed, but never reaches the else statement.  I keep getting all the output from the if statement everytime.  I am pushing to the main branch.  Not sure what I am missing?

```
stages:
  - add-license

Add-MIT-License:
  stage: add-license
  script:
    - echo "This is the current working dir $(pwd)"
    - echo "Job is running"
    - |
      if [ ! -f LICENSE ]; then
        echo "Adding MIT License..."
        echo "MIT License" > LICENSE
        echo "" >> LICENSE
        echo "Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy" >> LICENSE
        echo "of this software and associated documentation files (the 'Software'), to deal" >> LICENSE
        echo "in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights" >> LICENSE
        echo "to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell" >> LICENSE
        echo "copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is" >> LICENSE
        echo "furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:" >> LICENSE
        echo "" >> LICENSE
        echo "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all" >> LICENSE
        echo "copies or substantial portions of the Software." >> LICENSE
        echo "" >> LICENSE
        echo "THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED 'AS IS', WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR" >> LICENSE
        echo "IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY," >> LICENSE
        echo "FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE" >> LICENSE
        echo "AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER" >> LICENSE
        echo "LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM," >> LICENSE
        echo "OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE" >> LICENSE
        echo "SOFTWARE." >> LICENSE
        echo "MIT License file added."
      else
        echo "MIT License file already exists."
      fi
  only:
    - main
```

Comment: Hint: what do you do when you create a new file in your local working tree?

Comment: When I run the script locally, meaning I just take the echo part and put it in a bash file and run it, the LICENSE file gets created.  When this is ran through the pipeline it does not create the file.

Comment: The LICENSE file gets created during CI. But after the virtual machine stopped the file disappeared because you didn't put it anywhere. Hint: it's just a virtual machine; it doesn't automagically put files in your repository. Put it there yourself.

Comment: CI is running in a (bunch of) virtual machines. When a VM stopped every file created in it but not saved outside disappears. Your CI run creates the file but not saves it anywhere so file disappears when the virtual machine stopped. You need to save the file. The usual place to save is your repository. Hint: how do save a new file in the repository.

Comment: when I echo stuff with the ">>" it means to save the file or to append to a file.  So from my perspective I am saving the file and writing it to the correct directory.  Please explain what I am missing.  I am not following.  When I run this same script locally it saves the file, but not through the CI pipeline.  What should I be doing different?

Comment: "*when I echo stuff with the ">>" it means to save the file file or to append to a file.*" Only inside a virtual machine. When the VM stops the file disappears. When you run the script locally it's preserved in your local filesystem, When you run the script in CI it's created in the VM's filesystem but the filesystem is ephemeral — it's destroyed with the VM immediately after CI run is finished. You need to save the file outside of the CI VMs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push to a repo from within a gitlab CI pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716044/how-do-i-push-to-a-repo-from-within-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  I needed to add a commit and then push it to the repo.

```
stages:
  - add-license

variables:
  MIT_LICENSE: |
    MIT License
    
    Copyright (c) <year> by <username>
    
    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the 'Software'), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
    copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED 'AS IS', WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
    SOFTWARE.

Add-MIT-License:
  stage: add-license
  script:
      # Configure GIT Info
    - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
    - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
    - |
      if [ ! -f LICENSE ]; then
        echo "Adding MIT License..."
        
        # Replace <year> with the current year
        CURRENT_YEAR=$(date +"%Y")
        LICENSE_CONTENT=$(echo "$MIT_LICENSE" | sed "s/<year>/$CURRENT_YEAR/g")

        # Replace <username> with the Git username
        GIT_USERNAME=$(git config user.name)
        LICENSE_CONTENT=$(echo "$LICENSE_CONTENT" | sed "s/<username>/$GIT_USERNAME/g")
        
        echo "$LICENSE_CONTENT" > LICENSE
        echo "MIT License file added."
       
        # Add LICENSE to git
        git add LICENSE
        git commit -m "Add MIT License"
        git push -f https://CI_PIPELINE:$ACCESS_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git HEAD:main
        echo "Changes Pushed to Gitlab."
      else
        echo "MIT License file already exists."
      fi
  only:
    - main
```